# Java GUI without any other process

Tags: java, user-interface

I want to run a Java application from the command-line which has a GUI, but I don't want to use gnome or anything else. I had heard about something like this called Qt in C++, but i'm unsure if anything like this exists for Java.

My Java application will be running on a Beaglebone with a Debian distribution.

Comment: I don't understand your issue. You want to add GUI to your Java app or avoid it ?

Comment: Qt is a UI framework, gnome is a desktop environment for linux-based distributions, it has nothing to do with Qt. Can you clarify what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: Are you looking for AWT/Swing? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Swing_%28Java%29 - it's a Java GUI framework.

Comment: Do you mean something like ncurses?

Comment: I think he has an application that has a GUI. And he wants to start it from the command line without any desktop environment / window manager and have a GUI available.

Comment: Jaydee, that is 100% correct.

Comment: Closest thing I could find to what you are looking for: http://sdljava.sourceforge.net/ Dormant since 2005 though and you'll be rolling your own GUI widgets if you want them. Maybe it is possible to rewire AWT/Swing to paint to  new target though? Not sure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Qt_Jambi

This is a java binding for Qt.

---

***After comment from @Arkady:***

If you want to use a so-called "headless" operating system, without GUI...
Java will detect being on a headless system (say Linux without X-Server), and not be able to du GUI or even fonts.

There is a JNodeOS, java operating system, that has its own frame buffer and so on. But that is a bit radical.

My best guess would be to install a minimal Window Manager, or look at what is done at Raspberry Pi and java FrameBuffer solutions: http://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=81&t=59721

Comment: I think the question is more about native Java tools. In that case, AWT or Swing are better fit.

Comment: Does swing require a desktop environment / window manager?

Comment: Yes, AFAIK. It cannot run in a console, only started in a console on a desktop. As almost always the Linux GUI is handled by an X-Server, you can use a **remote desktop** on another machine. (The following link concerns "headless": http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/javase/headless-136834.html )